# Which is correct word "Log in" or "Login"

Tags: word-choice

Which word is correct **Log in** or **Login**?

For an employee's daily log, to fill it's in and out timing. 
What word is preferable in that context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Login in" and "login" are just like "back up" and "backup", and many other similar expressions.

The double word form is a verb, while the single word form is a noun.

Try parsing the verb or pluralizing the noun.  There's only one way it sounds right:

- "*He logs in every day*", not "*He logins every day*".
- "*There were several logins yesterday*", not "*There were several logs in yesterday*".

or:

- "*He backs up the data*", not "*He backups the data*".
- "*The backups are stored elsewhere*", not "*The backs up are stored elsewhere*".

In your example, you could say "*The employee logs in upon arrival and logs out upon leaving*" and "*The logins and logouts of all the employees are recorded in this book*".

Comment: You should use "login" where you need a noun, and "log in" where you need a verb.

Comment: @Swapnil You could use "-ing" form (of the verb) to think of it. "Logging in..." and absolutely not "Loginning" :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of your time and efforts.